# Class cannot cast to another class

Tags: java, casting, compareto

i'm working with BST data structure and i have a class called *TimeInterval*

```
private TimeInterval StartTime,EndTime;

public TimeInterval(Time time,Time time2){
    StartTime = (TimeInterval) time; //cannot convert from Time to TimeInterval
    EndTime = (TimeInterval) time2; //cannot convert from Time to TimeInterval
}

@Override
public int compareTo(TimeInterval that) {

    if (StartTime.compareTo(that.EndTime) > 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (EndTime.compareTo(that.StartTime) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What can i do to fix this problem and let the method compareTo work fine?
NOTE : i've tried to do this and it didn't work :

```
private Time StartTime,EndTime;

public TimeInterval(Time time,Time time2){
    StartTime =  time;
    EndTime =  time2;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(TimeInterval that) {

    if (((TimeInterval)StartTime).compareTo((TimeInterval)that.EndTime) > 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (((TimeInterval)EndTime).compareTo((TimeInterval)that.StartTime) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this TypeScript? Flow? JavaScript doesn't have type declarations.

Comment: sorry i'm new but i'm using eclipse

Comment: Eclipse is your **IDE** (Interactive Development Environment). It's what you use to type in and manipulate your programs. It is **not** the programming language that you're using. It *appears* that you're trying to write Java code.

Comment: please tag your question accordingly

Comment: ok sorry i thought that java and javascript are the same

Comment: It looks like the first problem is that your `StartTime` and `EndTime` fields should be of type `Time`, not `TimeInterval`. (They should also be named `startTime` and `endTime` to meet normal Java naming conventions.)

Comment: Well, a time interval is composed of a start time and an end time. Not of two other time intervals. These casts don't make any sense, StartTime and EndTime should be Times, not TimeIntervals, and should be spelt startTime and endTime. Your compareTo doesn't respect the contract of Comparable: it should be transitive: if A = B and B = C, then A = C. That's not the case with your implementation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java

Comment: i did all that but compareTo doesn't work it says that i have to cast the startTime and endTime to TimeInterval. then the problem doesn't solved

Comment: also my class is implements 'Comparable<TimeInterval>'

Comment: I think you need to take a step back, and answer a few questions for yourself.  What *is* a `TimeInterval`?  How is a `TimeInterval` different from a `Time`?  What does it mean for one `TimeInterval` to be "greater" than another? (Longer duration? Later starting time? Later ending time? Later starting *and* ending times?)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do any casting, as both `StartTime` and `EndTime` have the type `Time`, and you are comparing the two directly.

```
private Time StartTime,EndTime;

public TimeInterval(Time time,Time time2){
    StartTime =  time;
    EndTime =  time2;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(TimeInterval that) {

    if (StartTime.compareTo(that.EndTime) > 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (EndTime.compareTo(that.StartTime) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, `camelCase` is recommended for naming your variables.

Comment: i did that and it shows me an error on method compareTo that is inside compareTo(TimeInterval that) and it says "the method cmpareTo(Time) is undefined for the type Time"

Comment: and the solutions that he gave me is
1- cast the startTime and endTime to TimeInterval
2- create method compareTo(Time) " this is not allowed in the project "

Comment: which `Time` class are you using?

Comment: Time is an interface

Comment: `public interface Time {
 int getHH();

 int getMM();

 int getSS();

 int getMS();

 void setHH(int hh);

 void setMM(int mm);

 void setSS(int ss);

 void setMS(int ms);

}`

Comment: `Time` should implement `Comparable` too then if it makes sense for `Time` instances to be comparable.

Comment: The problem is that `Time` is an interface , i cant let it implements `Comparable `

Comment: you can extends `Comparable`

Comment: to give you the complete idea of the program , i have 5 interfaces "List, SortedMap, Time, Subtitle, SubtitleSeq" and the important classes are "Time1(that implements Time), Subtitle1(that implements Subtitle), SubtitleSeq1(that implements SubtitleSeq), TimeInterval(that implements Coparable<TimeInterval>)"

Comment: this is a project and they gave us the interfaces and we are not allowed to change any thing on them

Comment: `Time` can extends `Comparable`, thus solving the missing `compareTo` method for `Time`. Ofc you will need to implement the `compareTo` method in `Time1`.  Anything other than that is getting pretty fundamental, and some Java tutorial will help, not from StackOverflow.